# Python logging not working

Tags: python, logging

I'm loading my logging configuration from a file. The log file is given below:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('../output.log','w')

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

And I create a logger using:

```
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.conf')
```

However, I do not see any logging output when I run my program. If I add a separate logger for my **main** module, then logging works as expected. But set up like this it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the name of your log file?

Comment: @HennyH added statement to show how I'm loading the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the logger creation *after* configuration.  The `logging.fileConfig` call will disable the pre-existing loggers which is why your logger isn't working.

Comment: Or alternatively set the keyword argument `disable_existing_loggers=False`.

Answer (score 1):

By creating the log file like so:

```
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

It will look for a file with the name with the value of `__main__`, which your **main** module will have equal to `"__main__"`. However the other modules you import will have `__name__` equal to the *module name* of the module.

Comment: That's not how I'm creating the log file. That's just how I'm creating the logger. And I've edited my post to show how I'm loading the lagging config file.

Comment: Regardless, shouldn't messages me forwarded to the root logger by the __main__ logger? Why aren't they being output?